# How do I allow concurrent access to the same route?

Tags: ruby, concurrency, sinatra, thin, puma

I've a simple Sinatra application with one long running route:

```
get '/jobs/new' do
  logger.info "jobs/new start. Thread = #{Thread.current.inspect}"
  sleep 10
  logger.info "end new..."
  erb :'jobs/new'
end

get '/jobs' do
  erb :'jobs/index'
end
```

I've concurrent access between routes, but not to the same route.

An example is, while a client invokes `/jobs/new`(long during access), another client can invoke `jobs` in parallel. But the parallel call for the same route doesn't work. In this case, Puma, the webserver, always calls the route with the same thread:

```
jobs/new started. Thread = #<Thread:0x007f42b128e600 run>
10 seconds later...
jobs/new ended. Thread = #<Thread:0x007f42b128e600 run>
jobs/new started. Thread = #<Thread:0x007f42b128e600 run> <-- new call. Has to wait till first has finished
```

The other route is being called by different threads. And while route 1 is running:

```
jobs/new started. Thread = #<Thread:0x007f42b128e600 run>
2 seconds later...
jobs started. Thread = #<Thread:0x007f541f581a40 run> <--other thread
8 seconds later...
jobs/new ended. Thread = #<Thread:0x007f42b128e600 run>
jobs/new started. Thread = #<Thread:0x007f42b128e600 run>
```

I tried running the app with Thin in threaded mode and with Puma, with the same behavior

Comment: It's not necessary, nor is it recommended to add keywords to titles, unless they're part of the normal sentence structure of the title. Keywords, like "Sinatra:" are not used by searches, nor do they help the key-work ranking of the question. Instead, they reduce the readability of the title. Keywords, and searches, occur based on the tags you add to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you did, I think it was not right.

Running this code:

```
# config.ru
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

get '/jobs/new' do
  logger.info "jobs/new start. Thread = #{Thread.current.inspect}"
  sleep 10
  logger.info "end new..."
  "jobs/new"
end

run Sinatra::Application
```

with puma:

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 2.7.1, codename: Earl of Sandwich Partition
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292
Use Ctrl-C to stop
I, [2013-12-12T14:04:48.820907 #9686]  INFO -- : jobs/new start. Thread = #<Thread:0x007fa5667eb7c0 run>
I, [2013-12-12T14:04:50.282718 #9686]  INFO -- : jobs/new start. Thread = #<Thread:0x007fa566731e38 run>
I, [2013-12-12T14:04:58.821509 #9686]  INFO -- : end new...
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2013 14:04:58] "GET /jobs/new HTTP/1.1" 200 8 10.0132
I, [2013-12-12T14:05:00.283496 #9686]  INFO -- : end new...
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2013 14:05:00] "GET /jobs/new HTTP/1.1" 200 8 10.0015
^C- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
- Goodbye
```

Results in 2 different threads!

Comment: Yes indeed, when I invoke the route from to different browsers (FF, chrome), the calls are concurrent. When I call it from the same browser (different tabs), the behavior is like my example in the question. Why??

Comment: It seems that the browser prevents calling the same url concurrently.

Comment: don't use a browser when debugging such issues. rely on the cmd line, use `wget` or `curl`